# Shared attribute across multiple class instances (but not ALL instances)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have a class, say `Cat` which I currently define as follows.

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, clone_population=0, **kwargs):
        self.clone_population = clone_population

    def clone(self):
       props = vars(self)
       props['clone_population'] += 1
       return Cat(**props)
```

Cats can either be born by instantiating them directly (birther cats) or be cloned from other cats.

Now, what I can't figure out, is how to keep track of the clone population of a given birther cat such that the birther itself and all its clone can access the population number

**Example, based on current code** (here's where I'm at)

```
cat_mandu = Cat()  # A new cat is born 
cat_mandu.clone_population
# 0
```

As expected, we have no clones yet. If I make a clone:

```
cat_mandu_v2 = cat_mandu.clone()  # catmandu is cloned
cat_mandu.clone_population, cat_mandu_v2.clone_population
# 1, 1
```

Now, I get, correctly, 1 for both the birther cat and the clone cat, since the `var` dict is being fed across clones. However, if I clone the clone:

```
cat_mandu_v3 = cat_mandu_v2.clone()  # clone the clone
cat_mandu.clone_population, cat_mandu_v2.clone_population, cat_mandu_v3.clone_population
# 1, 2, 2
```

I don't get the population updated in the birther cat. I want my behavior to have a property which tracks the number of clones of a given birther cat, and the birther and all its clone keep track of the same number which is the current clone population.  So the correct answer should be `2 2 2` and not `1 2 2`.

*Note* that if a new birther cat `meawsome = Cat()` is born, we should just see 0 clone population (`meawsome.clone_population = 0`), since it has not been cloned yet.

I appreciate help or hints to the appropriate technique which can give such behavior.

Comment: Isn't it the case that your `cat_mandu_v2.clone_population` is 0 and not 1 when it is created via the first `clone()`?

Comment: Before initiating new cat I am incrementing the clone pop by one

Comment: You don't do anything with `kwargs` in your `__init__`, and in fact, `cat_mandu_v2.clone_population` is 0, not 1, when used as shown.

Comment: I had a mistake. I edited the question to correct this. This is also a toy example based on real porblem I have,  so it's not fleshed out a lot.... In any case this is example of what's not working...I hope to get a hint of what technique can make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you're copying the integer counting the number of clones when you pass it with `**props` to the new instance's `__init__` method. From then on, there's no connection maintaining the count between generations. Each clone parent and their clone child will start with the same count, but others in the lineage will count separately.

To fix that, you'll need to have *all* instances derived from the same original cat linked to a single source where the count lives. I think the first uncloned cat (the "progenitor" of the lineage) is the most natural place for it to live, but you can do otherwise (for instance, you could create a separate `Lineage` class). Here's how I'd do it:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self, progenitor=None):
        if progenitor is None:
            self._clone_count = 0
            self.progenitor = self
        else:
            self.progenitor = progenitor

    def clone(self):
        self.progenitor._clone_count += 1
        return Cat(self.progenitor)

    @property
    def clone_count(self):
        return self.progenitor._clone_count
```

With this design, there's only one *real* clone count per lineage, stored in the progenitor cat instance's `_clone_count` attribute. All cats in the lineage of clones will be able to access that count though, and the `clone_count` property exposes it to the outside (without other code needing to know all the implementation details).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the change being reflected in current object attribute is actually the behavious I want,it just doesn't go deep enough when I clone from clones. I updated the question a little bit to make it more clear

Comment: Ah, I had misunderstood the direction of the error. The real problem is that you don't get a continued connection then once you've copied the values using `**props`. I'll update to give a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting instead of passing around all the vars we just pass around a reference to a list. So we establish two rules:

1) Any cat created not from cloning creates it's own list and passes its reference down to any clones

2) Any cat created from cloning takes the reference from it's parent and passes that down to further clones.

The end result is that all cats that originate from the same cat will all have the same reference to the same list.

Here's an example:

```
class Cat:

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        if parent is None:
            self.parent = [0]
        else:
            self.parent = parent
            parent[0] += 1

    def clone(self):
        return Cat(self.parent)

    @property
    def clone_population(self):
        return self.parent[0]
```

Some test examples:

```
c = Cat()
print(c.clone_population)
>>>0
b = c.clone()
print(c.clone_population)
>>>1
d = b.clone()
print(c.clone_population, b.clone_population)
>>>2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be to consider using some type of `CloneTracker` metaclass.

This might have the advantage of being able to define CloneTrackers that provide different behavior depending on the object being cloned!

```
class CloneTrackerSingleton(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        cls._instance = None
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

class SimpleCloneTracker(metaclass=CloneTrackerSingleton):
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
    def inc(self):
        self.total += 1
    def get_total(self):
        return self.total

class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tracker = SimpleCloneTracker()

    @property
    def clone_pop(self):
        return self.tracker.get_total()

    def clone(self):
        SimpleCloneTracker().inc()
        return Cat()
```

As an example:

```
c1 = Cat()
c1.clone_pop  # 0
c2 = c1.clone()
c1.clone_pop, c2.clone_pop  #  (1, 1)
c3 = c2.clone()
c1.clone_pop, c2.clone_pop, c3.clone_pop  # (2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This does not work exactly like I needed. If I add new non-cloned cat `s4 = Cat()`, then this new cat has population 2 even though it was not cloned...